# How to print meta description to posts?

Tags: plugin-wp-seo-yoast, post-meta

I want to show my meta description content above posts. But i don't know what function I need to call.

Resume: i want to put meta description from Yoast Seo above the posts body.

Answer (score 3):

You will want to make use of Yoast SEO's "WPSEO_Frontend" class. To display the meta description field content, you could do the following:

```
<?php
   if (class_exists('WPSEO_Frontend'))
   {
       echo WPSEO_Frontend::metadesc(false);
   }
?>
```

Comment: If i put your code it gives me a blank page. And if i put just "echo ..." i got this error "Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in /home/user999/public_html/mydomain.com/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo/frontend/class-frontend.php on line 809"

Comment: ok, let's see how you're implementing this code. I tested it and it works fine in a post loop, where the post has a Yoast SEO meta description filled in.

Comment: I'm implementing on archives.php for categories. I'm using "Meta description template" in "Titles & Metas" option from Yoast SEO.

Comment: Fatal error:  $this when not in object context in /home/..... and yes, the error occurs with the code within the loop.

Answer (score 3):

Solution:

```
<?php $object = new WPSEO_Frontend();
        echo $object->metadesc( false ); ?>
```

Comment: Some explanations could turn this fragment into an answer. ;)

Comment: +1 for this solution. This works like charm in and outside the loop. Thanks Ukelele.